# Server error from any action in Accounting module in Odoo 16

Tags: odoo-16, odoo-accounting

Installed Odoo 16 on Ubuntu 20.04 with Odoo Accounting 16.  Keep getting an error if I try anything with accounting (below is from trying to create a new bill). New to Odoo and appreciate any help.
[Error pg 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvBA6.png)
[Error pg 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoWdp.png)
All other modules seem to be working fine. Only the accounting module seems off and whatever I try I keep getting the error.  I tried looking at the files and line numbers within the trace back but did not see any regex expressions there (as I understand regex to be).

Comment: try to reinstall it with demo data enabled